# How to resolve "branch is ahead of 'origin/<branch>' by 10 commits"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

After the **git status** command in the vscode terminal, the following message appeared

```
On branch feat/02-autenticacao
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feat/02-autenticacao' by 10 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .gitignore
        modified:   package-lock.json
        modified:   package.json
        modified:   src/App.tsx
        deleted:    src/components/Form/FormLogin.tsx
        modified:   src/main.tsx

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        src/authConfig.ts
        src/components/AzureAuthentication/
        src/components/FormLogin/
        src/graph.tsx
        src/pages/
        src/styles/
        src/utils/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You haven't said how that's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely sure you want to discard 10 commits:

```bash
git stash push -u  # Save the current changes for later (including untracked files).
git reset --hard origin/feat/02-autenticacao  # Reset the branch to the origin version, discarding the commits.
git stash pop  # Restore the changes saved to the stash.
```

(There may be conflicts if some of the currently edited files were edited by those 10 commits.)